# How to rename a snapshot repository in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have registered a snapshot repository like this:

```
PUT /_snapshot/es152_prod_backup
   {
     "type": "fs",
     "settings": {
     "location": "/var/es/backup",
     "compress": true
     }
   }
```

Now I want to rename it to something more generic like:

> myapp_prod_backup

How can I do it?

Thanks,

Chandan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a new repository:

```
   PUT /_snapshot/myapp_prod_backup
   {
     "type": "fs",
     "settings": {
     "location": "/var/es/backup",
     "compress": true
     }
   }
```

and delete the old one

```
   DELETE /_snapshot/myapp_prod_backup
```